# Need help making a PHP login session last longer

Tags: php, session, authentication, duration

I am working on a site for a small (read: <50 users) nonprofit organization that I work with and my PHP knowledge is fairly limited.  Currently I have a login script that I found from a tutorial online.  The problem I am running into is that each user is logged out after about an hour or so.

Security really isn't an issue with the content and ideally I would like for someone to stayed logged in for multiple days or weeks.  However, any search on Google about sessions length nets me people looking to shorten the logout timer.

As far as code goes, once the login page compares username and password to the database and follows with:

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:index.php")
```

And on each protected page it starts with:

```
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login.html:);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `session_register` is depracated

Comment: it's better for you to reset the session timer once the user has any activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your .htaccess and put something like:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2000
```

2000 is in seconds.  Set accordingly!  This will tell the session garbage collector not to destroy the session for 2000 seconds.  Also, session_register is deprecated.

Comment: So I can simply add that line to .htaccess and set the value to 604800 for a week long login?  (60 x 60 24 x 7)  Also, as a bit of a side note: I know that session_register is deprecated but the script I pulled off Google uses it and it has been working fine for me so far.  How would I go about changing it to not use session_register and keep the same functionality?

Comment: Yes, the 604800 will work just fine. Instead of session_register use $_SESSION['username'] = 'whatever';.

Comment: Read @Raidenace's post as well.  It's very informative.  I should have gone into more detail ;)

Comment: @ChrisG I tried creating a .htaccess file and my only line is:
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 8640000
is there a reason why the session still times out after 30 min?

Answer (score 8):

Given your question and the scale of your userbase, I'd opt for a global setting change rather than attempt to customise session variables; It's simple, does what you need and required very little effort to apply to all users.

You can set your global session lifetime (as outlined in other answers) using an `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400 //this is one day in seconds
```

Or, you can also set it in your php.ini file - a snippet of which is:

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

For nothing but pure reference, the values you'd need to consider for long-term garbage-collection:

```
86400 = one day
604800 = one week
```

You can read more about garbage-collection(gc) [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP's default cookie based session management (which I believe you are, since you did not mention anything about changing how default session works) you can use:

```
session_set_cookie_params(7200); // in seconds...session will last for 2 hours now
session_start(); //once session cookie parameter is set, start the session..
```

`session.gc*` group of ini values are also used for this purpose, but remember that `gc` only recommends when the session should be garbage collected, and does not really mean it will happen then.

You can read about [cookie params here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and [garbage collection here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: You are correct in assuming I haven't changed anything in regards to cookies.  The first line of code you have, I assume that goes on each protected page as well?

Comment: yes, the best way is to put it in a session include file and include it in every page where session would be active.

Comment: If that is included in every page will it reset the session to 7200 everytime you go to a different page? In thoery the session would never end if you kept changing pages